# relocating weird angled pipes for bathroom sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, angle, relocating

I recently wanted to upgrade my bathroom vanity and the new one has drawers, so my pipes need to come straight out from under my sink.  The drawn image is what my old vanity looks like with the original pipes coming out.  How hard do yall think it would be to change it from this weird angle out of the corner of the wall to moving it right under the sink? I'm also very new to this, I have had to replace old pipes, but never relocating anything.  The spare bathroom has the same issue.

[image]

Comment: you need to take pictures no one know what this is my guess is that your sink was on the left side on the cabinet at first but someone moved it the the right side. i need pics tho i cant give any info on this drawing

Comment: Since you can keep everything hidden by the vanity, just cut out the drywall about 4 inches inside the vanity outline and the same off the floor. Post clear, well-lit photos of that and we'll have an actual conversation. As it is, there's not really a question here.

Answer (score 1):

This is common, particularly with "new space saving" vanity cabinets from that great big scandinavian furniture retailer. You will either need to get very creative, potentially including cutting pieces out of the back of the vanity cabinet drawers, or you will need to **open the wall and reconfigure your drain lines to accommodate**.

> How hard do yall think it would be?

This would depend entirely on your knowledge and experience with drains, sinks, and plumbing; and in the worse case, with drywall repair. I did this exact job in my bathroom and it was a lot of work but worth it in the end:[image][image]